# Read 'hidden' input for CLI Dart app

Tags: input, dart, command-line-interface

What's the best way to receive 'hidden' input from a command-line Dart application? For example, in Bash, this is accomplished with:

```bash
read -s SOME_VAR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `io.stdin.echoMode` to false:

```
import 'dart:io' as io;

void main() {
  io.stdin.echoMode = false;

  String input = io.stdin.readLineSync();

  // or 

  var input;
  while(input != 32) {
    input = io.stdin.readByteSync();
    if(input != 10)  print(input);
  }

  // restore echoMode
  io.stdin.echoMode = true;
}
```

Comment: Why the `while(input != 32)`? Is the space supposed to mean the input is finished?

Comment: Yup, just an example I created or copied from somewhere a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly extended version, key differences are that it uses a finally block to ensure the mode is reset if an exception is thrown whilst the code is executing.
The code also uses a waitFor call (only available in dart cli apps) to turn this code into a synchronous call. Given this is a cli command there is no need for the complications that futures bring to the table.

The code also does the classic output of '*' as you type.

If you are doing much cli work the below code is from the dart package I'm working on called dcli. Have a look at the 'ask' method.

https://pub.dev/packages/dcli

```
  String readHidden() {
    var line = <int>[];

    try {
      stdin.echoMode = false;
      stdin.lineMode = false;
      int char;
      do {
        char = stdin.readByteSync();
        if (char != 10) {
          stdout.write('*');
          // we must wait for flush as only one flush can be outstanding at a time.
          waitFor<void>(stdout.flush());
          line.add(char);
        }
      } while (char != 10);
    } finally {
      stdin.echoMode = true;
      stdin.lineMode = true;
    }

    // output a newline as we have suppressed it.
    print('');
    return Encoding.getByName('utf-8').decode(line);
  }
```

Comment: I found out that the new version of dshell is at https://pub.dev/packages/dcli in case anyone is interested.